# Typeorm find returning wrong dates

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using Typeorm with Postgres. When I insert some data that have `CreateDateColumn`, it's saved with `timestamp without time zone` in UTC format using the right offset (GMT-3). But when I use `Entity.find()` or `createQueryBuilder.getOne` the results are 3 hours ahead. It's look like is a problem in TypeOrm, cause executing the query from `getSql` the dates are with the correct values. I don't know if it interferes, but the Postgres is running in Docker.

e.g.:
I insert a entity on 6:00(GMT-3)

It's inserted on database as 9:00

Run Query on database manually -> 9:00

Run TypeOrm generated query manually on database -> 9:00

Typeorm result -> 12:00